# Store content from an html table to a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

All i want to do is to store the user entered values to a database.There is a table and it has many text boxes where the user enters his input.Upon clicking submit button the values should be stored in the mysql table.
I'm getting some errors right now.I'm completely new to php,Below I've attached the code and screenshots.

```
//workingcode.php
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","tom","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//select Database

mysql_select_db("sms", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dept_info", $con) or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo '<tr> <th>Sl No</th> <th>USN</th> <th>Name</th><th>code1</th><th>code 2</th> <th>code 3</th> <th>code 4</th> <th>code 5</th> 
                <th>code 6</th> <th>code 7</th> <th>code 8</th></tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['usn'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td>";
    for ($i=1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
        echo "<td> <input type='text' name='sl[{$row['usn']}][$i]' size='2' /> </td>" ;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '
<form action = "insert.php" method = "post">
<div align="bottom">
<input type = "submit" align = "BOTTOM" value = "Proceed">
</div>
</form>
';
?>
```

I've linked this to an insert.php file as shown below..

```
  <html>
<head>
<title>Marks Entry Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Student Marks Entry Results</h1>

    <?php


        $insertData = array();
foreach ($_POST['sl'] as $usn => $codes) {
    foreach ($codes as $sl) {
        $insertData[] = sprintf("('%s', %d)", mysqli_real_escape_string($usn), intval($sl));
    }
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","tom","");
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
//select Database

mysql_select_db("sms", $con);

$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (usn, code1) VALUES\n" . join(",\n", $insertData);
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
echo mysql_affected_rows()." Marks inserted into database.";
} else {
echo "An error has occurred. Not added.";
}
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
//The description of the table which i made for this is
/*mysql> desc mytable;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| usn   | varchar(50) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| code1 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code2 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code3 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code4 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code5 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code6 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code7 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| code8 | int(2)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.01 sec)
*/
```

Comment: Please post the errors you're getting so we can help solve the problem.

Comment: I get the following error.  Student Marks Entry Results  An error has occurred. Not added."

Comment: why use mysql on one page and mysqli on another? Is this YOUR CODE?

Comment: first one was mine ..second one was taken from a tutorial..I'm completely new to php..sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

The textboxes are not inside any form tag so when you hit submit the value of textboxes doesn't get post back to server...Try following.

```
echo '<form action = "insert.php" method = "post">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['usn'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['name'];
    echo "</td>";
    for ($i=1; $i <= 8; $i++) {
        echo "<td> <input type='text' name='sl[{$row['usn']}][$i]' size='2' /> </td>" ;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '
<div align="bottom">
<input type = "submit" align = "BOTTOM" value = "Proceed">
</div>
</form>';




  //insert.php

<?php




    $insertData = array();
    foreach ($_POST['sl'] as $usn => $codes) {
        foreach ($codes as $sl) {
            $insertData[] = sprintf("('%s', %d)", mysqli_real_escape_string($usn), intval($sl));
        }
    }

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","tom","");
    if (!$con) {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //select Database

    mysql_select_db("sms", $con);

    $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (usn, code1) VALUES\n" . join(",\n", $insertData);
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
       echo mysql_affected_rows()." Marks inserted into database.";
    } else {
    echo "An error has occurred. Not added.";
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for the help sir..I edited my code as you suggested,but I get only the Student Marks Entry Results and blank page..I sense something wrong with my insert.php code

Comment: Is your error display enabled in PHP.ini? if not enable it. Also can you tell me the last statement after which the error is thrown?

Comment: I've turned error display to on in php.ini file which was in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini..the only output i get is till this line <h1>Student Marks Entry Results</h1> below which nothing is displayed.

Comment: post the result of print_r($_POST);

Comment: Your are using $db->query($query); which is wrong in your context, use mysql_query($query); in you have a separate database class you can create an object of it and call it like this $db->query($query); same goes for other $db-> references...

Comment: I've updated it sir...now i get the error as "An error has occurred. Not added."

Comment: echo "An error has occurred. Not added."; change this to echo "An error has occurred. Not added.".mysql_error(); and see what mysql error has occurred...

Comment: Student Marks Entry Results
An error has occurred. Not added.Query was empty

Comment: $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (usn, code1) VALUES\n" . join(",\n", $insertData));
 replace this with $query = "INSERT INTO mytable (usn, code1) VALUES\n" . join(",\n", $insertData)";

Comment: Now i get no o/p and also the color indentation of the below shown code changed. $result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
echo mysql_affected_rows()." Marks inserted into database.";
} else {
echo "An error has occurred. Not added.".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close();
?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: echo $query; and run your query directly in phpmyadmin or any other tool to see what is causing the error...

Comment: #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 ....too many values are getting inserted to the same row....so i need to correct my query ....

Comment: sorry for my mistake...I changed the table name..data is being inserted now...but not as intended....Thanks a lot for the help sir.God bless you.