# Storing file paths in a MySQL database for music app

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications, audio-player

I have a large number of MP3 files on my web server or file system and I would like to be able to extract the basic information(title, artist, etc) along with the path to the file without having to manually enter a query for each individual file. Is there a way for me to dynamically grab the pathnames to all of thes files at once and store them in a MySQL database?

Comment: Have a look at [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php), let PHP draw you a table of filepath, metadata and some inputs for your custom data and then send it to another PHP script which will save it. (if you have no idea how to save, use this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916319/store-content-from-an-html-table-to-a-mysql-database))

Comment: @JanLegner Is this something I would have to do through a web page or I can do this through the backend with MySQL? My issue is I want to basically dump this information into the database and then from there access it and use for my web app.

Comment: You can do it easily with just a backend part of course. Just go through the first 2 links I provided and see the examples. Then in a while loop browse through a directory, use some if statement (`if (preg_match("/\.mp3$/i", $fileName))`){ /* hero comes code saving path and some info into MySQL */ }